# Glitches and other problems with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to draw a rather smooth surface in a 3D graph with `pgfplots`.

1)
It shows however, some glitches (spikes on the smooth surface),
which I guess due to some numerical issues in the basic package.

[image]

Package: pgfplots 2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1 (git show 1.4.1-1-g64c9e95 )

2)
I want to plot it in a bit bigger size. However, the scale command only acts on the
textual parts, but not on the plot.

3)
I want to emphasize some parts of the surface,
like x values, for .2<=x<=.4, with a label,
and a point say at x=0.6, y=0.25, maybe with a label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,backgrounds,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
        ylabel=Serial percentage ,
        xlabel=Overhead percentage, 
]
\addplot3[
    mesh,
    samples=41,
    domain=0:0.8,
    scale=2
]
{ 
(3./(3-1))* 
( 1.- ((x+.25*(1.+y))/(x+3.*.25)))
};
\addlegendentry{$\alpha_{eff}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any spikes, and the `scale` command does scale the whole plot for me. Are you perhaps using an old version of PGFPlots? The current version is 1.12. Also, what compiler are you using (`pdflatex`)?

Comment: In a couple of day I refreshed my setup, and yes, I am using pdflatex

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the output you get? What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: You should update your PGFPlots version, there have been several substantial updates and bugfixes in recent versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the main issue (glitches) are solved by updating PGFPlots to a newer version. For the remaining issues (How do I add labels to the plot) there are plenty of examples on TeX.SX.